# Jquery Block on my document .ready function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code,

I added JS Script file to my Master page.

```
 <script src="/Scripts/Jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This Below code I have in my master page.on document.ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#question'), css: { width: '275px'} });
        }); 
</script> 
<div id="question" style="display:none; cursor: default"> 
    <h2 class="padding"><br />An unexpected system error has occurred while processing your request.<br /></h2>
    <h3>We apologize for this inconvenience.<br />
     Please report this error to your system administrator with the following information:<br /><br />
     Session id is:</h3>
     <input type="button" id="OK" value="OK" /> 
</asp:Content>
```

On my Document.ready Function my BlockUi is not working?

can any body tell me why its not working?

thanks

Comment: Is the ready callback being called at all? Throw an alert in there or something. If so, it's time to bust out firebug, put a breakpoint on the blockUI line and see what it's doing.

Comment: Yes I keep alert i can see my alert box there but its not blocking my UI? thanks

Comment: It could be a number of things...  First, are you including the blockUI library?  If so, is it actually loading?  The HTML looks a bit invalid as well...  There's no closing tag for div#question.  But there is a closing asp:Content tag.  Perhaps the markup needs to be corrected?

Comment: Have you checked the JS error you're getting?  
Is your JS code in the HEAD of your document?

Comment: Thanks I am not getting any JS Error at all.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going over some of the syntax in the [blockUI Documentation](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) and they had the following example:

```
$.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' });
```

so for your case you might need:

```
$.blockUI({ message: $('#question').html(), css: { width: '275px'} });
```

I'm not sure if that .html() might help, you may want to try innerHtml() as well. I haven't used blockUI before, so just a shot in the dark here.

Hope it helps :)

EDIT: I stand corrected, your syntax seems to be correct according to the demo found [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog). It must be some syntax or reference error somewhere.

The issue could also be a lack of jQuery referencing in your script files (as blockUI requires at least v1.2.3+ of jQuery. Try putting the following in your scripts area to see if that solves your problem, or you could use the link below (in comments) to download the most recent version.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it possible that you could show us the code for the references at the top of your page / masterpage? That could help a bit with the troubleshooting.

Comment: Are you also including the required jQuery files? The blockUI plugin requires at least jQuery v.1.2.3. So you should also have that file included in your Scripts section. You can access the most recent jQuery here, http://jquery.com/.